# In tensorflow.metrics, difference between precision_at_k and precision_at_top_k?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, information-retrieval

In the tensorflow python API, `tf.metrics` features a few metrics for Information Retrieval.

In particular:

- `tf.precision_at_k` and `tf.precision_at_top_k`
- `tf.recall_at_k` and `tf.recall_at_top_k`

What is the difference between the `_at_k` and `_at_top_k` metrics?

The [API documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/metrics/precision_at_k) does not seem to give information on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Looking at their implementation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.8/tensorflow/python/ops/metrics_impl.py), `precision_at_k` is a simple wrapper around `precision_at_top_k`. The difference is actually mentioned in the API docs: `precision_at_k` expects a tensor of logits as `predictions` whereas `precision_at_top_k` expects the predictions to be the indices of the top k classes. In essence, `precision_at_k` simply performs `tf.nn.top_k` on the `predictions` and then calls `precision_at_top_k`.